# Why do I need to .strip when debugging using python via Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I have a driver for some hardware I'm testing (i'm a test engineer) - this is written in C++ and I have it set up in Visual Studio. The output is a dll but that's largely irrelevant.

I write all my API tests in Python (just because I like python) using ctypes , and so I decide to knock up a quick test for a new function - in this case its a frequency generator. Because I'm currently more interested in the hardware and driver (white-box testing) I just want a single line as follows:

```
while action != 'exit':
    action = raw_input("Enter a frequency  or 'exit':")
    //do stuff
```

However, whilst this worked fine in pycharm, and cmd prompt, when I call this python script through visualstudio as the debugger, it always fails. 
A colleague told me to chomp (or pythonwise, strip) the input, and this works, but I'm keen to know why.

ie the working code :

```
while action != 'exit':
    action = (raw_input("Enter 'Frequency' or 'exit':")).strip()
    // do stuff
```